# slf4j, logback, the target compressed file named exist already

Tags: logback, slf4j, logback-classic

logback 1.1.5 + slf4j 1.7.4.

Rollover at midnight

```
 00:00:00,163 |-INFO in c.q.l.co.rolling.helper.RenameUtil - Renaming file [/opt/wls/appl/log/out.log] to [/opt/wls/appl/log/out.log1294410077875834.tmp]
 00:00:00,164 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.Compressor - ZIP compressing [/opt/wls/appl/log/out.log1294410077875834.tmp] as [/opt/wls/appl/log/archive/out/out-2018-09-04.10.zip]
```

But after some seconds rollover starts again

```
 00:01:52,551 |-INFO in c.q.l.co.rolling.helper.RenameUtil - Renaming file [/opt/wls/appl/log/out.log] to [/opt/wls/appl/log/out.log1294522459498363.tmp]
 00:01:52,551 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.Compressor - The target compressed file named [/opt/wls/appl/log/archive/out/out-2018-09-04.0.zip] exist already.
```

There are 2 applications on 2 virtual servers of WLS. Both of applications use separate home folder with your own logback.xml.

logback.xml is

```
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${PRG_HOME}/logs/out/out-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="ASYNC_COMMON" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>32000</queueSize>
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
</appender>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `<prudent>true</prudent>` to your `RollingFileAppender`. This should allow for multiple JVMs writing safely to the same file.

There are some [restrictions](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudentWithRolling) that apply to `prudent` mode, though. Log-file compression is not allowed, for example.

Comment: this doesn't meet the requirements. Logs should be compress.

Comment: separates logback.xml was added for every application.
but error still occured

Comment: using a simple `cron` job to compress the files after they were 'rolled' is not an option for you? b/c I don't see a way to do both with logback

Comment: why after applications start use separate home folder with your own logback.xml the error still occured?
every application use your own logback.xml from your own home folder and so write logs to different files.